# LinearLayout was covered by AppBarLayout

Tags: android

My `haha.xml` layout was covered by  `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`, how can i make the button on the `haha.xml` just appear under the AppBarLayout?
[image]

only **haha.xml** layout

[image]

**PS:**
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.william.test.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
       <include layout="@layout/haha" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**haha.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red">
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="按钮不可用1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a surrounding layout around the AppBarLayout+LinearLayout

Comment: @cricket_007 updated activity_main.xml contains all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `AppBarLayout` and `haha layout` by a `LayoutManager` to arrange UI elements
For example you can use `LinearLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
       <include layout="@layout/haha" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this help

Comment: This fixed my AppBar overlapping the content below.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.fragments.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <include layout="@layout/haha" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated activity_main.xml. Actually it contains what you added.